# Does MongoDB aggregation $group command run on all shares

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, sharding

When I run an aggregation on a sharped MongoDB environment. If $match matches documents on multiple shards, does the next command in the pipeline ‘$group’ then run on multiple shards?

Or does all the matching data go to a single shard?

If it goes to a single shard, which shard will it go to?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you run with shards or not, it will perform the aggregation automatically on all the shards if the data is in different shards.